# Project Euler #1 Sum of multiples of 3 and 5 python implementation

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-2.x

Given:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>   Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

My Solution:

```
def sum_multiples(num, limit):
    """ Calculates the sum of multiples of a given number.
    Args:
        num: The multiple.
        limit: The upper limit.
    Returns:
        The sum of the terms of a given multiple.
    """
    sum = 0
    for i in xrange(num, limit, num):
        sum += i
    return sum

def sum(limit):
    return (sum_multiples(3, limit) +
            sum_multiples(5, limit) -
            sum_multiples(15, limit))

print sum(1000)
```

Is there any better or more *pythonic* way? I have used generators for a very large calculation. Also, how can I get the running time for a given `N`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It'd be more pythonic to use the built-in `sum` function instead of writing one yourself:

```
sum(xrange(num, limit, num))
```

However, this is still doing way too much work -- you don't need to do a for-loop for a series sum, there's a closed-form solution:

```
def sum_multiples(n, lim):
    last = (lim - 1) // n
    return n * (last) * (last+1) // 2
```

EDIT: Also, don't call your own function `sum`, since you hide the built-in one that way.

```
def sum35(limit):
    return (sum_multiples(3, limit) +
            sum_multiples(5, limit) -
            sum_multiples(15, limit))

print sum35(10)   # 23
print sum35(1000) # 233168
```

Comment: I would still prefer some better name than `sum35` :)

Comment: Agreed, but naming things is hard. :D I'd probably call it `euler_1` or something, tbh.

Comment: Very true! `Naming and caching are two most difficult problems in CS`.

Answer (score 9):

Your Python code looks good, but your solution can be slow for large values. You can compute the sum of multiples in O(1). We can first observe there are `floor(limit / num)` terms that are divisible by `num` and smaller then `limit`. Finally we can calculate the result using the Gauss sum formula.

```
def sum_multiples(num, limit):
  no_of_multiples = (limit - 1) // num
  return no_of_multiples * (no_of_multiples + 1) / 2 * num
```

For your example `sum_multiples(3, 10)`, the `no_of_multiples` will be 3 (those are 3, 6, 9) and we can express their sum as:

```
3 + 6 + 9 = 3 * (1 + 2 + 3) = 3 * ((3 * 4) / 2)
```

You can get the running time under Linux by using the `time` utility, writing in your terminal `time python3 script.py` for example.

Comment: For example I have 15 then multiples of `3=3, 6, 9, 12, 15`, multiples of `5=5, 10, 15` and multiples of `15=15`. Hmm, it seems to work.

Comment: Try more examples on paper till you understand the idea better. ;)

Comment: Also, can you please help me to find the running time of my solution. Because in general the running time is wrt to input size but in my case I have just constant numbers.

Comment: First, running time is different from algorithm complexity. Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915842/difference-between-time-complexity-and-running-time). If you want to learn more about complexities just [search](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) [on the internet](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/103951/best-resources-to-really-understand-run-time-complexity) and read a book.